# Is $\Gamma(p) := \text{Ker}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ a "standard" subgroup?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $\Gamma(p) := \text{ker}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p/p))$.

Viewing $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ as an analytic group, is there a formal group law $F$ in three variables, defined over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, such that $\Gamma(p)$ is isomorphic to the group on the set $(p\mathbb{Z}_p)^3$ whose group operation is given by $F$?

Here, "standard" is the terminology used in Serre's lecture notes on Lie Algebras and Lie Groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Let $g = \begin{pmatrix}1+a & b\\ c & 1+d\end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma(p)$ with $a,b,c,d\in p\mathbb{Z}_p$.
Then the condition $\det g = 1$ can be rewritten $(1+a)(1+d) = bc+1$, so that $d = (1+a)^{-1}(bc+1) -1$, which is a power series in $a,b,c$ with zero constant term. Then you can turn the group law and the inverse expressed as polynomials in $a,b,c,d$ into power series in $a,b,c$.

Comment: And of course there’s no reason to restrict $a,b,c,d$ to elements of $p\Bbb Z_p$: you can take them in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak M$ of any complete local $\Bbb Z_p$-algebra, such as the integers of a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$.